# Cypress not resolving promise inside session setup function

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm writing some Cypress tests using Cucumber/Gherkin and I'm stuck at the following.

I have a simple function to create Cypress session where I retrieve token and save it inside of a cookie:

```js
export const sessionFunc = (userId: string) => {
  cy.session(userId, async () => {
    const token = await getAppToken()
    cy.setCookie('name', token)
  })
}
```

I'm using `cy.request()` method to retrieve token like this:

```js
export const getAppToken = () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cy.request('some url').then((response) => {
      resolve(response)
    })
  })
}
```

During test execution (after 30 second timeout) I'm getting error that my promise never got resolved and this failed the test. Adding `return` keyword before `cy.request()` does the same thing, however removing `cy.request()` and resolving any value makes test pass normally and promise is resolved. I should also mention that if I call this function anywhere outside of session setup it works fine.

```js
export const getAppToken = () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve('OK') // This works
  })
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I would really like to use async / await since it makes code look much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do all of that without the Promise and async/await.

```js
export const sessionFunc = (userId: string) => {
  cy.session(userId, () => {
    cy.request('some url').then((response) => {
      cy.setCookie('name', token)
    })
  })
}
```

It looks like the `cy.request()` is never starting, probably because of the Promise wrapper.

Cypress operates by scanning the test and loading commands into the queue, before starting to actually run the commands. Most likely it does not put `cy.request()` into the queue, or does so in the wrong place.

Comment: I know I can do it that way but my code is longer and more complicated than that and it is much cleaner to use async / await approach. I guess it's safe to assume that this is an actual bug in Cypress?

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? Cypress is not designed to work with your particular code. If you want more advice, change the question to be closer to your actual code. If you can't get passed the need for async/await, switch to Playwright.